# dynamodb "GetItem operation: Requested resource not found" / "The provided key element does not match the schema"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I don't know how to explain this:

```
$aws dynamodb scan --table-name Todos-dev  
...
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "todoId": {
                "S": "9e6e7f0f-97ee-4289-93b9-cb1bf46d5190"
            },
            "createdAt": {
                "S": "2019-12-29T07:11:09.581Z"
            },
            "name": {
                "S": "test4"
            },
            "userId": {
```

and

```
$ aws dynamodb get-item --table-name Todos.dev --key file://key.json

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetItem operation: Requested resource not found
```

where

```
$ cat key.json 
{"todoId": {"S": "9e6e7f0f-97ee-4289-93b9-cb1bf46d5190"}}
```

serverless.yml

```
    TodosTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: todoId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: createdAt
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: dueDate
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: todoId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: createdAt
            KeyType: RANGE
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}
        LocalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: ${self:provider.environment.INDEX_NAME}
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: todoId
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: dueDate
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
```

The message I'm getting "The provided key element does not match the schema", comes from docClient.delete, tried multiple combinations to specify Key, nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**key element does not match schema**

Your table has a hash key and a range key. Your `key.json` file has only the hash key. When using `getItem`, you must provide the full (hash and range) key. If you want to get multiple values for the same hash key or if the range key value is unknown, you can use only the hash key, but you must use they `query` api instead.

**resource not found**

You are using `Todos-dev` in your scan call, but `Todos.dev` in the getItem call.